# Add single line at the end of multiple files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, replace, ide, jetbrains-ide

I need to add a single text line at the end of many configuration files (*txt-like* format). The line is identical for all files.

Is there an automatic command to do it once for all files? I have tried to search in the options of IntelliJ *replace in files* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> window) but I can't find anything to do it automatically.

[image]

As you can see, there are options for everything (case, file type, etc...) but nothing that is for my case.

Comment: Can you please add an example to what you want? what have you tried? and What have you got?

Comment: How about replacing a thing on the end of the file with that + the thing you need? Otherwise I would write a script.

Comment: What OS are you running the IntelliJ on? Windows or *nix?

Comment: Re: the downvotes here, it's not that this is _exceptionally_ bad, just meta effect: This was referenced from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406006/post-incorrect-answer-first-copy-correct-solution-from-another-answer-later-ge?cb=1 - going forward, if you would like to avoid downvotes, probably review the [help] and in particular [How to ask.](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use ***Replace in Files*** (*Edit → Find → Replace in Files*, or Ctrl+Shift+R in Windows and Linux / ⌘+Shift+R in Mac) to replace this regex:

`(.)\Z`

with this:

`$1\nThis is your line`

in any files you need. That's all.

---

Explanation:

The regex `(.)\Z` matches and captures the last character in the whole file:

- `(.)` matches and captures any character
- `\Z` matches EOF (end-of-file)

And the replacement uses it to add your line after it:

- `$1` uses the first capture group (i.e. the previously matched character, to avoid removing it)
- `\n` introduces a new line
- `This is your line` is the line you want to add

You may use the *File mask* option to select the files you want to change:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: do you have also the version for line start?

Comment: @Lore `\A` matches start-of-file, so for inserting a line at the start of each _file_ just search for `\A(.)` and replace with `This is your line\n$1`. This will insert your line at the "top" of each file. Inserting something at the start of each _line_ would involve using the matching character `^` instead of `\A`, but I won't go into detail because I doubt that's what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 13):

Here's how I would do it:

1. From the File menu open the `Settings` and select `Editor > General`. Scroll down and find `On Save` section and tick the `Ensure every saved file ends with a line break`. This should look something like this:

[image: settings UI]

2. Then, in your project, go to `Edit > Find > Replace in Path` or `Ctrl+Shift+R` (On Windows & Linux) or `Shift+Command+R` on MacOS.
3. In the `Replace in Files` window tick `File mask:` and specify your config files. **Note:** you can use wild cards! *For example, I'm using three files `config_1.txt config_2.txt config_3.txt` so the mask would be `config_*.txt`. Here's what's in the config files:

[image: config files before replace]

4. Then select `Search with regex` - those `.*` on the right-hand side below the pin icon. Also, select `Directory` from `In Project Module Directory Scope`. See the screenshot below.

For 5 & 6 regex credit goes to [@walen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66636067):

5. Type `(.)\Z` in the first search field.
6. Type `$1\n` and then type the line you want to append the files with. For example `$1\n yet another config line`.
7. Click `Replace All`.

[image: replace UI]

8. Your config files should be appended and look like this:

[image: config files after replace]

9. If you're on Linux, save yourself all the trouble and just do this:

```sh
echo "your new line" | tee -a config_*.txt
```

PS. I've tested this approach on IntelliJ Community and PyCharm Professional.

Comment: Your alternative solution using `tee` will also be useful to all IntelliJ users on Windows that have Git Bash installed (probably most of them: Git for Windows installs it by default, I think), as well as Mac users too (they also have a Unix shell available).